# set form width of inline form- responsive bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I was trying to embeds three different forms in a single horizontal row.

The first(shop), second(locality) and third(search) form element should occupy 50%,30% and 20% (6,4 and 2 bootstrap col unit) of total horizontal row.

[image]

In mobile view, each three form element should be adjust in individual row.
[image]
I tried following:

```
<div class="row search-form-wizard">
    <form role="form" class="">
        <div class="form-group form-group-lg">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <label class="sr-only" for="select2_sample6"></label>
                <input type="hidden" id="select2_sample6" class="form-control select2 input-lg"  >
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group form-group-lg">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <label class="sr-only" for="selectextra_sample6"></label>
                <input type="hidden" id="selectextra_sample6" class="form-control select2 input-lg" >
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <button type="button" class="btn green btn-lg btn-block"><i class="fa fa-search"></i> Search</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Is this the correct approach?

Should I use bootstrap inline form for this purpose?

I tried using inline form, but its difficult to set width of each form elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct you just need to adjust for small screens with col-xs-12 & change md to sm.. xs is mobile...

```
<div class="row search-form-wizard">
    <form role="form" class="">
        <div class="form-group form-group-lg">
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <label class="sr-only" for="select2_sample6"></label>
                <input type="hidden" id="select2_sample6" class="form-control select2 input-lg"  >
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group form-group-lg">
            <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                <label class="sr-only" for="selectextra_sample6"></label>
                <input type="hidden" id="selectextra_sample6" class="form-control select2 input-lg" >
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-12">
            <button type="button" class="btn green btn-lg btn-block"><i class="fa fa-search"></i> Search</button>
        </div>
     </form>
</div>
```

Comment: with col-xs-12, there is no gap between three elements

Comment: This is where margins come into play.

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify a small (`col-sm-*`) width for each one. **Edit** like another answer `col-xs` for extra-small screens.

`<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">`

`<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12">`

`<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-12">`

Comment: col-xs-* is for mobile.

Comment: If you have applied custom margins, padding etc it can throw out the 12 grid system and you may have lose one of the 12 to handle it

Comment: That's why you apply margins and padding to inner elements not the column element itself.